# SQL query to select one value form one table and other from another table and also display count

Tags: mysql, rdbms

[image]

[image: **enter image description here**]

These are the two tables and i am stuck in the query between these two tables.
I need list the seller names and the numbers of different types of smartphone that they sell. Also, the results should be sorted in descendent order of Number of Phone Types.
In one column i need seller name and i another i need total number of phone the seller sell.

like lisa mcdonals sell 3 different types of phones.

Comment: Can you share what you tried so far? And where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: TABLE names are SELLER and SMARTPHONE

Comment: I have tried this query:

SELECT SELLER.SellerName, SMARTPHONE.SellerID 
FROM SELLER, SMARTPHONE
WHERE SMARTPHONE.SellerID= (SELECT COUNT(SellerID) FROM SMARTPHONE);

Comment: You figured out to use the count() function but you need to select it in your main query and drop the subquery. Also use explicit joins in oracle. When you consider these two things you will find that you also need a group by statement to get your query to work. See my answer for a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
select S.sellerName, P.productID from seller S join product P on S.SellerID=P.SellerID order by P.productID;
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work if you adjust the table names to your own:

```
SELECT Seller.SellerName,
       Product.ProductID
FROM   Seller
       LEFT JOIN Product
              ON Product.SellerID = Seller.SellerID
ORDER  BY ProductID DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to join the two tables and group the result by `SellerName` so you can count the number of phones each seller sold.

```
select SellerName, count(ProductID) from Seller
    join Smartphone using (SellerID)
    group by SellerName
    order by count(ProductID);
```

Mind that these might not be your table names since you did not provide them.